# not receiving error from remote call, goes all the way to timeout Go gRPC + micro + protobuf

Tags: go, rpc, grpc-go, protobuf-go, go-micro

I've recently started learning microservices using Go and I've stumbled upon some tutorial that was using micro, gRPC and protobuf. After some time I realized that I do not receive any error messages from the cli that was created to communicate with the microservice. Code below is able to reproduce this.

```
import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "github.com/asim/go-micro/v3/client"
    "github.com/asim/go-micro/v3/cmd"
    "github.com/asim/go-micro/v3/logger"
    pb "github.com/dbielecki97/grpc-errors/proto/greeter"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/codes"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    err := cmd.Init(cmd.Name("cli.greeter"))
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    log.Println(os.Args)

    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        log.Fatal(errors.New("Not enough arguments, expecing name."))
    }

    name := os.Args[1]
    c := pb.NewGreeterService("service.greeter", client.DefaultClient)

    greet, err := c.Greet(context.Background(), &pb.Request{Name: name})
    if err != nil {
        s, ok := status.FromError(err)
        if ok {
            if s.Code() == codes.InvalidArgument {
                logger.Fatal("Incorrect name!")
            }
        } else {
            logger.Fatal(s.Message())
        }

    }

    logger.Info(greet.Message)

    os.Exit(0)
}
```

```
import (
    "context"
    "github.com/asim/go-micro/v3"
    "github.com/asim/go-micro/v3/logger"
    pb "github.com/dbielecki97/grpc-errors/proto/greeter"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/codes"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
)

type greeterservice struct{}

func (g greeterservice) Greet(ctx context.Context, req *pb.Request, res *pb.Greeting) error {
    logger.Info("Name :: ", req.Name)
    if req.Name == "Dawid" {
        logger.Info("Correct name")
        res.Message = "Hello Dawid"
        return nil
    }
    logger.Warn("Incorrect name")
    return status.Error(codes.InvalidArgument, "Bad name")
}

func main() {
    service := micro.NewService(micro.Name("service.greeter"),
        micro.Version("latest"))
    service.Init()

    err := pb.RegisterGreeterServiceHandler(service.Server(), &greeterservice{})
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    err = service.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
}
```

```
syntax = "proto3";

package greeter;

service GreeterService {
  rpc Greet(Request) returns (Greeting) {}

}

message Request {
  string name = 1;
}

message Greeting{
  string message = 1;
}
```

When client is run with argument **Dawid** everything works as expected, but if I try anything else I do expect to get an error in client with message **Bad name**, but what I receive is just a timeout after default 5s of waiting time.

```
2021-05-31 16:26:36  file=client/client.go:40 level=fatal {"id":"go.micro.client","code":408,"detail":"call timeout: context deadline exceeded","status":"Request Timeout"}
```

Repo link : https://github.com/dbielecki97/grpc-errors

Comment: it should work just fine. I have a similar setup in my project and works correctly. Are you sure the logger is correct in your code. I see 2 separate log statements -  log and logger.

Answer (score 0):

solved by update protoc & protoc-gen-go version
I use this

//  protoc-gen-go v1.27.1

//  protoc        v3.14.0

you can try this or high version